# C++ Is it possible to 'delete' element from an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to make new array which has `size - 1` than my 'main array'.
And there is problem I cant declare `string newArray[oldArray.length()-1]`.

Is it this possible in C++ ?

Comment: Use `std::vector`. For one, it has a `size` function that remedies the problem of your example calling `length` on something that isn't a class (assuming `oldArray` is a built-in array).

Comment: Thanks but the problem is: my array is array of char of string i mean: string str = "ABC"; and i want co delete "A" and have  str = "BC" ;/

Comment: `std::string` has `erase()` and `replace()` methods for removing/replacing characters: `str.erase(0, 1)` or `str.replace(0, 1, "")`.  Or use its `substr()` method to create a new `std::string` value: `str = str.substr(1)`.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible to delete an element from a static array.  You can, however, shift the subsequent elements down one slot and then ignore the last slot.  You can use a separate variable to keep track of how many usable elements are in the array.

Alternatively, use `std::vector` to create a dynamic array.